# Flask static file content type is text/html after redirect

Tags: python, html, flask

I have run into a problem with static files after a `redirect` in Flask.
The web app I am writing will redirect users after logging in for the first time to a site where they need to change the default password they've been provided. On this site my custom stylesheets are entirely broken and images won't display either. 
A quick inspection in the Chrome dev tools showed that after the redirect the content type for the all files from the static folder is set to `text/html`. I suspect that this is the issue.

In my template html the stylesheet is linked in the following way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/colorVariables.css') }}">
```

The stylesheets and images work fine on every other page of the app and also if you go to the exact same page without the redirect.

The redirecting part looks like this:

```
if user.first_login:
    return redirect(url_for("change_password"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. The redirect was happening in a function run with `app.before_request`. Wrapping the routes with the function manually solved the problem.